# Saving shiny app as a function

Tags: shiny

I am trying to build a small shiny app, which I would like to save as a function (The method is explained [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/function.html))

While the app works fine, I am facing a strange problem. My app renders a plot (among a few other output). However, the plot is not always rendered on the Browser. At times, the plot is displayed on the R Studio's output pane. And the behavior appears to be fairly random (i.e. at times it works with the plot correctly getting displayed on the browser whereas often times the output just gets plotted on R Studio)

I am giving a very simplified version of my code below retaining the key elements and structure of the app:

sampleApp <- function(input_data,y){

```
require(shiny)
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("variables"),
                 selectInput........#add other input widgets

    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot_output"),
              dataTableOutput...#few other output

  )
), 
server = function(input, output) {

  funcA <- reactive({
  #Generates a formula expression basis user inputs
  })

  fun_plot <- reactive({
    #Generates a plot output, calls funcA in the process
  })


  event_output <- eventReactive(input$ActButton,{

   # I have an action button..The plot (and other output) gets updated
   # when the button is clicked..
  })

  output$plot_output <- renderPlot({

    event_output()$plot_output

  })

  # other render output functions      
  }
 )
}
```

Any inputs/guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I met similar problem before when the global environment have something can conflict with the shiny app. You can try restart R session for this, and better keep global environment relative clean.